# Need example of JBoss EAP 6.1 access log configuration in xml

Tags: jboss

I can't find any description of how to configure access logging for JBoss EAP 6.1 except https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/185383 which requires a subscription. 
Can someone show an example on how to configure access logging with name of log file and file rotation?
Now I have this config in standalone-full-ha.xml but how do I control file name and enable log rotation?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
...
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
   <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %{User-Agent}i %{JSESSIONID}c">
        <directory relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" />
    </access-log>
</virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided, it would seem that that you can set `prefix` attribute on the `directory` element you showed in your config, like this:

```
<directory relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" prefix="access_log_prefix_" />
```

As for file rotation, you should be able to configure that by adding `rotate` attribute to the `directory` element, please see [WildFly docs](http://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20EAP/6.0.1/subsystem/web/virtual-server/access-log/configuration/index.html) for that.

Now, I can't really confirm if this works since I don't have EAP 6 handy right now but I hope it helps you figuring it out, though. I can try to dig out something from the EAP docs later on.